# Get info user Facebook SDK iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I followed a little 'guides online, but I can not figure out how to get the username of the user such as Facebook. 
The login and session work properly. 
But I can not just take the values ​​of the current user. 
This is the working code

```
 if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
    // create a fresh session object
    appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];

    // if we don't have a cached token, a call to open here would cause UX for login to
    // occur; we don't want that to happen unless the user clicks the login button, and so
    // we check here to make sure we have a token before calling open
    if (appDelegate.session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        // even though we had a cached token, we need to login to make the session usable
        [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState status,
                                                         NSError *error) {



            NSLog(@"SESSION FACEBOOK OK");

           // how i get username ?
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Learn how to use the Facebook [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph).

To request the [user info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph#userinfo):

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
   if (!error) {
      // Success! Include your code to handle the results here
      NSLog(@"user info: %@", result);
   }  else {
      // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
      // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors   
   }
}];
```

Comment: I have tried this but still the session is active the code does not enter the if ...

Comment: Please follow the code from the link step by step, you'll get that. Give some time and try; and if you find any difficulty then let me know